# Understanding the Graph of a Multinomial Distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, graphing-functions, mathematica, geometric-interpretation

I am trying to understand exactly what information the graph of a multinomial distribution is supposed to convey.

The thing I find strange is that a binomial distribution is graphed in two dimensions and contains information about two fundamental outcomes, i.e., heads and tails on a coin. I would expect the three dimensional graph of a multinomial distribution to describe a "three-sided coin."

However, in Mathematica, the function for a multinomial distribution only allows two outcomes to be entered, and they must sum to probability $1$, leaving no room for an implicit third outcome.

[image]

The multinomial distribution graph in three dimensions seems to contain exactly the same information as the binomial distribution graph in two dimensions. In fact, the nonzero data can be seen (in the above example and in the Mathematica documentation) to be contained within a two-dimensional, diagonal slice of three-dimensional space.

Should a three-dimensional multinomial distribution PMF describe three fundamental outcomes, or if not, what extra information does the extra dimension allow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Removed original post for not answering the question*

---

## Edit

From the documentation:

[image]

It appears that you are really only plotting a binomial distribution, you just happen to be plotting it with 2 axes, but it is intrinsically binomial as you can see above - all nonzero probabilities lie on the line $x + y = 10$.

Further, you can see that when you only input two probabilities (the `In[2]` line) that you get a PMF which corresponds to a binomial (`Out[2]`). When you input 3 probabilities, you get a truly multinomial distribution, as evidenced by `In[3]` and `Out[3]`.

I guess this is just the syntax/definition that Mathematica uses - I don't use it much.

Comment: Hmm, I was getting my setup from Wikipedia which says, "In probability theory, the multinomial distribution is a generalization of the binomial distribution. For example, it models the probability of counts for each side of a $k$-sided die rolled $n$ times."  The $k$-sided die has the same property as the coin which you call unfair, right?  Once you know the probability of $k - 1$ outcomes, Kolmogorov axioms determine the probability of the final outcome.

Comment: There are different interpretations of the multinomial distribution. I see more clearly what you are asking now - just as the binomial dist describes a 2 sided coin but only has 1 axis , your coin has 3 sides but its distribution only has 2 axes. You can think of each point on this 2D plane as saying "Out of n tosses, I got x of side 1 and y of side 2". From there you know how many of side 3 you got, which is why you don't have a third axis (omitting the PMF value axis)

Comment: This is exactly how I would expect the multinomial distribution to function.  However, as exemplified above, Mathematica requires the supplied probabilities to sum to $1$.  I can assign probability $.8$ to $x$ and $.2$ to $y$, but not $.8$ to $x$ and $.1$ to $y$ (leaving $.1$ for $z$ implicitly).  If I try to assign $.8$ and $.1$, it will draw an entirely blank graph.

Comment: Check my edit above